# How to filter logic in SQL where element is not present for one of the user

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table, and I need to find out the person name who dont have Iphone?
Ex. query should give from the below table as Mike.

I am trying to built logic using group by on name and Items where Item not equal to Iphone or by using 2 table but unable to get the result, can anyone suggest ?

| Name | Items |
| --- | --- |
| Simon | Iphone |
| Simon | Tablate |
| Simon | Watch |
| Simon | Laptop |
| Jim | Iphone |
| Jim | Tablate |
| Jim | Watch |
| Jim | Laptop |
| Mike | Tablate |
| Mike | Watch |
| Mike | Laptop |

Comment: **iPhone**, surely :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have table, and I need to find out the person name who dont have Iphone?

Using your table, you can use aggregation:

```
select name
from t
group by name
having sum(case when item = 'Iphone' then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

The `having` clause counts the number of rows with iphones.  The `= 0` says there are none for the name.

Answer (score 0):

I like gordons answer but this might be easier to understand:

```
select name
from table
where name not in 
(select name 
from table
where item like 'Iphone')
```

If you need only a single record for each name go for this at the end:

```
group by name
```